# How to replace or recode values by map()

Tags: r, tidyverse

Here is my df(just an example of course)

```
  B73   Lo1016 LxB2  LxB3  LxB4 
1 AA    AA     AA    AA    AA   
2 GG    GG     GG    GG    GG   
3 GG    GG     GG    GG    GG   
4 GG    GG     GG    GG    GG   
5 GG    GG     GG    GG    GG   
6 CC    GG     CC    GG    CC   
7 GG    AA     GG    AA    GG
```

What I want to do is to recode all genotypes in df: if one value keeps the same as the couterpart in
column B73, then it is defined as "B"; same as that in Lo1016, "A"; none of them, NA.

I have finished this with two-layer "for" function(codes attached below), but I want to imporve by map_dfr() or map_dfc(). However I have no idea to define a function to replace or recode genotypes...Would you mind offering some advice kindly? Thank you very much!

```
for (j in 1:7) {
  for (i in 1:5) {
    if (df1[i,j] == df[i,1]){
     df1[i,j] = "B" 
    }
    else if (df1[i,j] == df[i,2]){
     df1[i,j] = "A"
    }
    else {
     df1[i,j] = "NA"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No `for` loops (*please* ;-):

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  mutate(
    across(LxB2:LxB4, ~ case_when(
      . == B73    ~ "A",
      . == Lo1016 ~ "B",
      TRUE        ~ ""[NA] ) )
  )
#   B73 Lo1016 LxB2 LxB3 LxB4
# 1  AA     AA    A    A    A
# 2  GG     GG    A    A    A
# 3  GG     GG    A    A    A
# 4  GG     GG    A    A    A
# 5  GG     GG    A    A    A
# 6  CC     GG    A    B    A
# 7  GG     AA    A    B    A
```

FYI, `"NA"` and `NA` are different things. If you want the former, just change `""[NA]` to `"NA"`. (The use of `""[NA]` vice simply `NA` is because `case_when` requires all return values to be the same class, and `NA` is of class `logical`; there are over six different classes of `NA`, and in this case we need `NA_character_` ... but `""[NA]` is code-golf shorter.)

---

Data

```r
dat <- structure(list(B73 = c("AA", "GG", "GG", "GG", "GG", "CC", "GG"), Lo1016 = c("AA", "GG", "GG", "GG", "GG", "GG", "AA"), LxB2 = c("AA", "GG", "GG", "GG", "GG", "CC", "GG"), LxB3 = c("AA", "GG", "GG", "GG", "GG", "GG", "AA"), LxB4 = c("AA", "GG", "GG", "GG", "GG", "CC", "GG")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is really helpful! Honestly I have never used case_when before. Is it correct of my understanding: case_when could conduct simiar things as if~else but in more effective way?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. `case_when` can be way to avoid nested `ifelse` calls